# On distributive modules

Tags: ring-theory, modules

Is there a ring $R$ (with identity) such that for any right module $M$ the lattice of submodules of $M$ is distributive?

Answer (score 3):

No.

Take a simple module $S$ for the ring, and consider the sum $S\oplus S$ and its submodule $T=\{(s,s)\mid s\in S\}$.

Look at $T\cap(S\oplus \{0\}+\{0\}\oplus S)$ and $(T\cap S\oplus \{0\})+(T\cap \{0\}\oplus S)$