# Linear sum of intersections of submodules

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, modules

Let $R$ be a commutative ring and let $Q$ be an $R$-module. Let $M, N, P$ be submodules of $Q$ without satisfying any additional requirements. Let $M+N$ denote the linear sum of submodules.

What can be said about the sum of intersections
$$(M\bigcap P) + (N\bigcap P)?$$

Is it contained in the intersection $(M+N)\bigcap P$, that is, is it true that

$$(M+N)\bigcap P\supseteq (M\bigcap P) + (N\bigcap P) ?$$

Or is it the other way around, that is,

$$(M+N)\bigcap P\subseteq (M\bigcap P) + (N\bigcap P)?$$

Or is it undecided, meaning it depends on the concrete case and hence, there is no generally valid inclusion?

Answer (score 2):

This is asking if the lattice of submodules of $Q$ is a [distributive lattice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributive_lattice) or not. A module whose lattice of submodules is a distributive lattice is called a distributive module.

If $Q$ is distributive, then the identity holds all the time. If it is not distributive, then there are submodules $M,N,P$ which fail the condition.

That $(M+N)\bigcap P\supseteq (M\bigcap P) + (N\bigcap P)$ is trivial. If $x+y\in (M\bigcap P) + (N\bigcap P)$, then $x+y\in M+N$ and $x+y\in P+P=P$, so $x+y$ is in their intersection. But the reverse inclusion is not always true.

In fact, [every nonzero (with identity) ring has a nondistributive module](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/630080/29335).

There are examples, though, of rings whose regular module $R_R$ is distributive. $\mathbb Z$ is such an example.

Comment: If $M$ and $N$ are $R$-modules with decreasing filtration, then by the formula in *Bourbaki*'s Commutative Algebra on page $234$, Exercise $6,c)$ we have $\left(\sum_{i+j=n}M_i\otimes_RN_j\right)\cap M_{i_0}\otimes_R N_{j_0}=M_{\sup(i, i_0)}\otimes_R N_{\sup(j,j_0)}$. This however contradicts your claim that $M\cap P+N\cap\subseteq(M+N)\cap P$ always holds true. Unless the authors in Bourbaki did make a mistake in fact or I do not understand their formula.

Comment: @FlaviusAetius You are talking about a result involving the tensor product. Why do you think it is relevant to the sum of submodules?  Can you not see that containment is trivially proven there?

Comment: You are right. I agree with you. I see the containment. And in fact, there is mistake in Bourbaki's book. There is a missing  sum sign before $M_{\sup(i, i_0)}\otimes_RN_{\sup(j, j_0)}$ over i and j which confirms your claim.